# Android ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE with video and text

Tags: android, video, text, android-intent, share

I'm trying to use the ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent to share at the same time a video file and a text.

Now,  this works in GMAIL (video in the attachments and text in the body of the mail), however I want to do the same in Whatsapp too, but it doesn't appear in the list of apps of the intent.

My code is the next:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Descarga la app en...");

ArrayList<Uri> contenidos = new ArrayList<Uri>();

File file = new File(Environment
    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath()
    + "/Talking/"
    + nombreVideo
    + ".3gp");

Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

contenidos.add(screenshotUri);

//sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,screenshotUri);
sharingIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contenidos);
sharingIntent.setType("video/3gpp");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share video using"));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your code gonna work due the new updates to whatsapp, before this didn't accept this kind of intent (ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) because it accepts only one file at a time.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");    
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/UserImages/"+ ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId() + ".png"));    
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hello test");    
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably means Whatsapp does not support this kind of intent (ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).

Comment: That's correct. You can't help it. WhatsApp chose to accept only one file at a time.